# Performance of a trimming function

Tags: c++, performance, boost, stl, trim

My old Trimming function:

```
string TailTrimString (const string & sSource, const char *chars) {
  size_t End = sSource.find_last_not_of(chars);
  if (End == string::npos) {
    // only "*chars"
    return "";
  }
  if (End == sSource.size() - 1) {
    // noting to trim
    return sSource;
  }
  return sSource.substr(0, End + 1);
}
```

Instead of it I've decided to use boost, and wrote the trivial:

```
string TailTrimString (const string & sSource, const char *chars) {
    return boost::algorithm::trim_right_copy_if(sSource,boost::algorithm::is_any_of(chars));
}
```

And I was amazed to find out that the new function works much slower.
I've done some profiling, and I see that the function `is_any_of` is very slow.

Is it possible that boost's implementation works slower than my quite straightforward implementation? Is there anything I should use instead of `is_any_of` in order to improve the performance?

I also found a [discussion](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/02/133396.php) on this matter in the boost's mailing list, but I am still not sure on how can I improve the performance of my code.

The boost version that I use is 1.38, which is quite old, but I guess this code didn't change too much since then.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use your old implementation? It is fast and produces the expected results.

Comment: Why did you reimplement a working function?

Comment: I reimplemented it only because I expected boost to give a better performance. I still don't understand, why boost's performance is worse.

Comment: @Igor Oks: Because it uses much more abstraction. The boost-code that runs here (behind the covers) might be several hundred lines long, instead of a few string-operations.

Comment: @Igor:  Did you profile your code and determine that TailTrimString was a problem that needed fixing?

Comment: The Standard Template Library algorithms were written by mathematicians striving for performance. Boost, on the other hand, is written by a large community of people with varying intent.

Comment: @Igor:  Did your profiler narrow in on exactly what about your code was taking so long?  And are you sure its taking longer than it should?  Some operations are simply very expensive, especially when repeated millions of times per second.

Comment: @Igor, maybe you can take a slightly different approach, currently your trim function is non-destructive, could it be destructive? i.e. erase from source so that you save yourself a copy? Or may be take a reference to destination and call `assign` (rather than `substr`) - if it's still a bottleneck, you could try re-writing using the C functions...

Comment: @John Dibling: Yes, my profiler narrowed is_any_of. I am also sure that this is the only difference between the 2 versions that I compare.

Comment: @Igor:  No, I meant in your original code.  Did you profile your original code, and did it tell you exactly which part of your original function was consuming CPU?

Comment: Make sure you are testing **optimized** code. In my testing, the second version was slower by about 30%, but without optimizations, the second version was slower took about 300-400% longer. The second version is still slower but (perhaps?) not as slow as you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it possible that boost's implementation works slower than my quite straightforward implementation?

Of course.

> Is there anything I should use instead of is_any_of in order to improve the performance?

Yeah -- your original code.  You said nothing about it having a defect, or the reason why you re-implemented it using boost.  If there was no defect in the original code, then there was no valid reason to chuck the original implementation.

Introducing Boost to a codebase makes sense.  It brings a lot of functionality that can be helpful.  But gutting a function for the sole purpose of using a new technology is a big rookie mistake.

### EDIT:

In response to your comment:

> I still don't understand, why boost's performance is worse.

A hand-crafted function that is designed to do one specific job for one specific application will often be faster than a generic solution.  Boost is a great library of generic tools that can save a lot of programming and a lot of defects.  But its generic.  You may only need to trim your string in a specific way, but Boost handles everything.  That takes time.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question about the relative performance, the `std::string::find_last_not_of`, will wrap C string routines (such as `strcspan`), and these are very fast, however `boost::algorithm::is_any_of` uses (probably used to use, I'd hazard that in the later versions this has changed!) a `std::set` for the set of characters to look for and does a check in this set for each character - which will not be anywhere near as fast!

EDIT: just to add an echo, your function works, it's not broken, it's not slow, so don't bother changing it...

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question about the relative performance.

You are using  `boost::algorithm::trim_right_copy_if` which, according to the name, creates a copy of the input before trimming. Try using `boost::algorithm::trim_right_if` to see if that has better performance. This function will perform the operation in-place instead of on a new string.